# How to get the Coordinates of a Custom Image Cursor in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, image, graphics, drawing

```
 Bitmap hh = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile("example.png");
 Graphics.FromImage(hh);
 IntPtr ptr = hh.GetHicon();
 Cursor c = new Cursor(ptr);
 this.Cursor = c;
```

I use this code to create a custom image cursor. I want to retrieve the coordinates of this custom image cursor when on a `Click` event. So that these coordinates can be used to draw the image of this cursor in a picture box when clicked on the image loaded in the picture box. I'm doing this in C#.

I tried another approach

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Bitmap _bmp = new Bitmap(250, 250);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        panel1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(panel1_MouseDown);
        panel1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panel1_Paint);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(_bmp))
            g.Clear(SystemColors.Window);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point mouseDownLocation = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        label1.Text = mouseDownLocation.X.ToString();
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(_bmp, new Point(0, 0));
    }

    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(_bmp))
        {
            g.DrawString("Mouse Clicked Here!", panel1.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Location);
        }
        panel1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Image.Save(@"C:\test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

But when i try so save the image i get an Exception: *Object reference not set to an instance of an object*.

Please note that `panel1` in the code above refers to a picture box

Comment: Is the exception thrown when you are clicking the button? If so, you should check if `panel1` is `null` or the `Image` property of the panel.

Comment: Yes i receive the error when i click the button to execute the save command

Comment: You have null Panel1.image because you are painting it in paint method and NOT assigning it permanently to the image property.

Comment: I'm a Beginner Little Help needed Please.

Answer (score 2):

To get the coordinates of the mouse on a PictureBox you should not handle the OnClick event but the OnMouseDown, for example in this way:

```
private void pb_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) 
{
  Point mouseDownLocation = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
}
```

now you have the `mouseDownLocation` which contains the coordinates you were looking for.

Comment: Please show your code and explain what is not working. Edit your question so we have nicer code formatting than in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

i know the way to get the coordinate of mouse  you can code it like

Cursor.Position.X and Cursor.Position.Y to get the Coordinate under the mouse